# Вопрос по материалу в Universal Render Pipeline

Tags: c#, unity3d

Думаю простой вопрос. Начал изучать Universal Render Pipeline в Unity. Там делается материал с shader: Universal Render Pipeline/Lit Я правильно понял что там аналог Standart шейдера Normal map - Albedo, Normal Map, Occlusion Map это понятно, но где Height Map? И 2 слоя получаеться тоже нет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Standart безумный аналог всему, это целый комбаин. Фишка `UPR` в `ShaderGrapg` в котором ты можешь легко сделать любой шейдр сам, и там не будет лишнех функций. П.С. бампом(`Bump/Height Map`) давным давно не пользуются, нормали (`Normal Map`) же есть.